# Is there a way to disable this text box when I hover over a chrome tab?

Tags: google-chrome

This started happening to me 3 days ago when I updated my Google Chrome browser to the latest version. When I place my mouse over any tabs, it shows this box immediately. In the past, you had to hover over it for at least a second and the information would pop up, but now it is more large and apparent. Is there a way to turn this off? Because it is irritating me!!! [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.)Open Google Chrome web browser and type chrome://flags/ in addressbar.
2.)Search for "Tab hover card".
3.)Disable it from dropdown.[image]